# vb.net: datetimerpicker mindate fires value change

Tags: vb.net, events, datetimepicker

I have the following vb.net code:

```
Public Class TEMP
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'myDate.MinDate = Today.AddDays(1)
    myDate.Value = Today.AddDays(1)
End Sub

Private Sub HCheckOutDate_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myDate.ValueChanged
    MsgBox(myDate.Value)
End Sub
End Class
```

In this code the "myDate" is DateTimePicker GUI element.

If I run the code like this (note that one line is commented out) then everything works as expected: once I click on the DateTimePicker, the date selector appears, I select a new date and the ValueChange event gets fired so I see a messagebox with the selected date. If I select a new date again, the same thing happens again.

However! If I uncomment the line which sets the mindate property then selecting a new date the first time works as above but once I want to select a new date again whats happening is this:

1. Before the date selector appears the date changes back to the
   mindate and the valueChange event gets fired
2. Still before the date selector appears the date changes back to its
   original value and the valueChange event gets fired again
3. Now the date selector appears, I can select a new date and if I do then the valueChnage event gets fired again

So practically if the mindate is set then I see the event fired three times which doesnt make sense at all.

Any ideas how solve this problem?

Comment: I just tested what you describe and saw no such behaviour.  I'm using VB 2017 on the latest version of Windows 10 and targeting .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Just to make sure that its not my project I have just recreated what I wrote above and I see exactly the same behaviour. Using win7 with .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Setting the mindate it actually changes the date from 1/1/0001 to mindate, and that causes a datechanged event to be fired. In order to prevent the unexpected event, you have to remove the event by using Removehandler before changing the mindate and Addhandler after.

Comment: Yes, I can remove the eventhandler, but that wouldn't solve the problem at all. It just prevents the event to be fired when the form loads but thats it. The problem is that after selecting the date the first time every other consequent new dates fire the event three times. The mindate is not set after the form is loaded. (btw: just to make sure, I did what you suggested. The event is not fired when the forms load, which is fine. But orignal problem still occurs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I have found is not really a solution but a workaround. It seems that the DateTimePicker just doesnt work right if minDate property is set to the future eg: `myDate.minDate= today.addDays(1)` in my case.

Note1: the problem does NOT occur if the mindate is set to today, or even `myDate.minDate = today.addDays(-1)` works fine. It seems it has problems with the future "only".

Note2: in the new code I temporarily disables the valueChange event. Once when the form loads, so the initialization of the object does not fire the event and once when the event is fired because the user changed the date. The user might selected the current date (today), but really the first date we should apply is tomorrow so the value of the datetimepicker may change again. Disabling the event there means that the event fires only once.

As I said this is really only a workaround. I dont know how is it possible that the datepicker can't handle such an simple thing as `myDate.minDate = today.addDays(1)`

```
Public Class TEMP
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RemoveHandler myDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf myDate_ValueChanged
        myDate.MinDate = Today
        AddHandler myDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf myDate_ValueChanged
    End Sub


    Private Sub myDate_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myDate.ValueChanged

        If myDate.Value.Date = Today.Date Then
            RemoveHandler myDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf myDate_ValueChanged
            myDate.Value = Today.AddDays(1)
            AddHandler myDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf myDate_ValueChanged
        End If

        MsgBox(myDate.Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it a bit and it looks like it's a bit bugged.
If I changed the month, it went in a infinite firing event loop for no reason.

I came out with a ***solution***, and it might help you:

We have to change the event to handle, from `.ValueChanged` into `.TextChanged`.
The behavior of the programm will be the same as well as the user fellings but now it will not fire for no reason.

So basically:

```
Private Sub HCheckOutDate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(myDate.Value)
End Sub
```

---

***Remarks:***

Use `myDate.Value = Today` instead of `Today.AddDays(1)`.

`Today.AddDays(1)` means that your min date will be tomorrow (today + 1) and I think that this is probably why its behaviour is very weird.

---

***Remarks 2:***

Just to be sure that everything works fine, remove the handler in the load event form, as shown below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RemoveHandler myDate.TextChanged, addressOf HCheckOutDate_TextChanged
    myDate.MinDate = Today.addDays(1)
    'myDate.Value = Today.addDays(1) this is a repetition. MinDate will do the same thing
    AddHandler myDate.TextChanged, addressOf HCheckOutDate_TextChanged
End Sub
```

Then you can add it after the declaration of the `MinValue`, just to be sure that nothing will fire on these lines

Comment: Interesting that both of us see a different behaviour. The solution you suggested does not work for me though. Once I click to that little arrow dropping down the date selector I see the problem I had originally. BUT!!! Interesting to see that if I simply set the mindate to "mindate = today" and not "mindate = today.addDays(1)" then my program behaves as expected. Whats going on here?

Comment: @Istvanb to be honest I never saw `today.addDays(1)` but only `.today`. It very weird and very interesting that It didn't work for you. I recreated you example in a blank project and It was working fine with `.TextChanged`

Comment: I have never tried this before, but if I select lets say the month text in the datetimepicker and then hit ctrl+up then it works fine (both with valuechanged and textchanged events). If I hit the little dropdown arrow - which my users will use for sure - then I see the original problem no matter which event I use. Important that the first to event fire happen before the date selector even appears. If I dont use the .addDays(1) then the problem is gone except that of course users can select the current date which is undesired.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli this is not the point. And you are in the wrong comments section

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli that doesn't change anything

Comment: @Istvanb did you try my edited answer? it should work 100%

Comment: @simo Yes I did and I would accept your solution in no time if it would work for me, but unfortunately it doesnt. Your solution works fine if the text of the datetimepicker changes in a way that the user doesnt click to the little date selector dropdown (eg changing the month with ctrl+up.) Once I click to the dropdown arrow your code displays the the popup message three times. For me it seems that our logic is fine, but there is an issue with the datetimepicker itself. I wont upvote your solution as it didnt solve my problem. It has good points though and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @it works perfectly for me, I'm pretty sure that your [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example is not so complete and verifiable.